# How to undo accidental pod trunk push

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a framewor that I am trying to publish through Cocoa pods. After `pod trunk register` and verifying my email, I went to the terminal and entered-

```
pod trunk push
```

rather than

```
pod trunk push [spec_path]
```

Then I again do it the right way but, it is saying

> Unable to accept duplicate entry for: Framework 1.0.0

What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Public CocoaPods must be unique and `Framework` already exists. See http://cocoapods.org/pods/framework.

Comment: I can't find my framework in pods when I search it but when I try to re-do the process, I get the error: duplicate entry. How to delete a published pod framework? and how can I get it if, I can't find it by searching the framework name in cocoapods?

Comment: The definitive list is at https://github.com/cocoapods/specs